# How to statistically validate a threshold?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, threshold

I have a set of 3 parameters that were measured for several individual (each dot of the dotplot is one individual). I am trying to define subpopulations of individuals based on these measurements.

Empirically I have defined C and A/B thresholds that reflect a biological meaning (grey square).

However, I want to have some statistical measure that the threshold I have chosen makes sense. Which methods can I use (preferably in R) to make this decision more robust?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "makes sense."  What are you seeking beyond the "biological meaning" already ascribed to your thresholds?

Comment: It means that it makes sense that individuals with high B levels (low A/B ratio) have high C levels.
In this case its quite obvious that you have a separation at A/B ratio = 15. Below that value individuals are mostly B positive and above they are mostly B negative. However, if you chose A/B ratio = 20 you can also get a good distinction but with higher contamination of B negative cells. So, how can you define a value of threshold or quantify its accuracy? Is it enough to say that with A/B ratio = 15 I have 99% of B positive cells inside the square? Is there another way to express this?

Comment: If your interest is defining subgroups, have you considered the tools available in R for cluster analysis? See http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html